# how often does a value appear in a combination

Tags: combinatorics

Say I have a set of numbers **1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10** and I say **10 C 4** I know that equals **210**. But lets say I want to know how often **3** appears in those combinations how do I determine that?

Comment: For future reference, your edit would have been better as a separate question, since the solution will be significantly different than the original problem.

Comment: just made it another question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the [rule of product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product). Three is in the list, so that equates to $\binom{1}{1}$, so for the rest you have a choice of 9 numbers for a set of three, so $\binom{9}{3}$. Multiply these together to get the total:

$$\binom{1}{1}\binom{9}{3}$$

Comment: oh ok gotcha makes sense

Comment: @WillJamieson Doing 210 - 84 would give you the number of combinations where 3 **doesn't** appear, which is the exact opposite of what you want.

Comment: makes sense pretty straight forward im rust really rust with my combinations

Comment: So say I wanted to know how many times 2 and 3 appeared in the same set me answer would be $\binom{2}{2}$ $\binom{8}{2}$ correct?

Comment: No, for the number of times 2 or 3 appear, the answer would be the same. But say you wanted to find the number of times both 2 **and** 3 appear, the answer would be $\binom{2}{2}\binom{8}{2}$. Note that just like $\binom{1}{1}$, $\binom{2}{2}$ equals 1.

Comment: got it. Im trying to apply this concept to solve a problem in my hw. I am just going to add it to my original question, because its a long explanation

Comment: update posted..