# Determining probability of certain combinations

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Say I have a set of numbers **1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10** and I say **10 C 4** I know that equals **210**. But lets say I want to know how often **3** appears in those combinations how do I determine that?

I now know the answer to this is $\binom{1}{1}$ $\binom{9}{3}$

I am trying to apply this to solve a problem in my math book. School is over so I cant ask my professor, Im just trying to get a head start on next year.

There are 4 numbers **S,N,M,K**

**S** stands for students in the class **N** the number of kids going on the trip **M** My friend circle including me **K** the number of my friends I need on the trip with me to enjoy myself.

I have to come up with a general solution to find out the probability I will enjoy the trip If I am chosen to go on it.

So far I came up with $\binom{S-1}{N-1}$ /($\binom{M-1}{K}$ $\binom{N-K-1}{S-K-1}$)

it works for cases like 
`10 4 6 4` & `3 2 2 1` but dosent work for `10 10 5 3`

any help is appreciated

Comment: Since this is related to [another question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/387232), it would be good to refer each to the other (with links).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Corrected:**

First off, your fraction is upside-down: $\binom{S-1}{N-1}$ is the total number of groups of $N$ students that include you, so it should be the denominator of your probability, not the numerator. Your figure of $\binom{M-1}K\binom{N-K-1}{S-K-1}$ also has an inversion: it should be $\binom{M-1}K\binom{S-K-1}{N-K-1}$, where $\binom{S-K-1}{N-K-1}$ is the number of ways of choosing the $N-(K+1)$ students on the trip who are **not** you or your $K$ friends who are going.

After those corrections you have

$$\frac{\binom{M-1}K\binom{S-K-1}{N-K-1}}{\binom{S-1}{N-1}}\;.$$

The denominator counts all possible groups of $N$ students that include you. The first factor in the numerator is the number of ways to choose $K$ of your friends, and the second factor is the number of ways to choose enough other people (besides you and the $K$ friends already chosen) to make up the total of $N$. However, this counts any group of $N$ students that includes you and **more** than $K$ of your friends more than once: it counts such a group once for each $K$-sized set of your friends that it contains.

To avoid this difficulty, replace the numerator by

$$\binom{M-1}K\binom{S-M}{N-K-1}\;;$$

now the second factor counts the ways to fill up the group with students who are **not** your friends, so the product is the number of groups of $N$ students that contain you and **exactly** $K$ of your friends. Of course now you have to add in similar terms for each possible number of friends greater than $K$, since you’ll be happy as long as you have **at least** $K$ friends with you: it need not be **exactly** $K$.

There are $\binom{M-1}{K+1}\binom{S-M}{N-K-2}$ groups of $N$ that include you and exactly $K+1$ of your friends, another $\binom{M-1}{K+2}\binom{S-M}{N-K-3}$ that contain you and exactly $K+2$ of your friends, and so on, and the numerator should be the sum of these terms:

$$\sum_i\binom{M-1}{K+i}\binom{S-M}{N-K-1-i}\;.\tag{1}$$

You’ll notice that I didn’t specify bounds for $i$. $\binom{n}k$ is by definition $0$ when $k>n$ or $k<0$, so we really don’t have to specify them: only the finitely many terms that make sense are non-zero anyway..

Alternatively, you can count the $N$-person groups that include you and **fewer** than $K$ of your friends and subtract that from the $\binom{S-1}{N-1}$ groups that include you; the different must be the number that include you and at least $K$ of your friends, i.e., the number that is counted by $(1)$. The number that include you and $i$ of your friends is $\binom{M-1}i\binom{S-M-i}{N-1-i}$, so the number of groups that include you and fewer than $K$ of your friends is

$$\sum_{i=0}^{K-1}\binom{M-1}i\binom{S-M}{N-1-i}\;.$$

This is going to be a shorter calculation than $(1)$ if $K$ is small.

Comment: I dont think the equation for calculating the amount of friends that include me and fewer than K. for the Case 10 10 5 3. There is only one possible group, and your equation states that there are 5 groups with less than K friends in it. Which cannot be true

Comment: @Will: There was indeed an error, and a big one, in my analysis; I don’t know what I was thinking. It’s corrected now; the last formula now says correctly that there are no groups of $10$ that have fewer than $3$ friends: $$\binom40\binom59+\binom41\binom58+\binom42\binom57=1\cdot0+4\cdot0+6\cdot0=0\;.$$